# Artifact[ejb:MoGEMSEJB:MoGEMSEJB] is not a dependency of the project error when adding Maven module

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, ibm-rad

I am converting a `Java EE` project to a `Maven` project using `IBM Rational Application Developer (RAD)` which is based on `Eclipse`. `IBM`'s instructions say to add the web project as a module in the `EAR` project but I am getting the error "Artifact[war:MoGEMS_WEB:MoGEMS_WEB] is not a dependency of the project." when I update the Maven project. I have included MoGEMS_WEB as a dependency and it is listed as a dependency when I click on the Dependencies tab in the `EAR` pom.xml file. The `EAR` pom file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MoGEMSApp</groupId>
<artifactId>MoGEMSApp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <configuration>
            <version>5</version>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <security>
                    <security-role id="SecurityRole_1">
                        <role-name>Security Role</role-name>
                    </security-role>
                </security>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>MoGEMS_WEB</groupId>
                        <artifactId>MoGEMS_WEB</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/mogems</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>MoGEMSEJBClient</groupId>
        <artifactId>MoGEMSEJBClient</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>MoGEMSEJB</groupId>
        <artifactId>MoGEMSEJB</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>MoGEMS_WEB</groupId>
        <artifactId>MoGEMS_WEB</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```